# Location of user data files in iOS simulator for XCODE 4.5?

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

With XCODE 4.5 / Mountain Lion where are the user data files for the iOS simulator stored?

Previously they were in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/, but no more.

I have XCODE 4.5.1.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, the joke's on me! In this version of the OS, the folder ~/Library is hidden. The data files were there all the time.

To permanently unhide it, in Terminal enter the following command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```